Datadog "Query value" - how to set post-aggregation correctly?
I have a Micrometer timer, sending measurements of some duration.
This is being sent to Datadog.
In Datadog, I have a dashboard with a box, whose definition is:

This is how I understand it:

The first applied max already comes from Micrometer (I assume), and is the maximum from a client-controlled timespan (~1 minute).
The second max comes from Datadog's roll-up, possibly 4 hours chunks used when I choose a month long display scope.
The last applied max, at the beginning of the line, is applied to the results, and the largest value is chosen as the single one to display.

This shows a single value; I would expect it to be the maximum over the whole displayed time period (let's say 1 month), which is around 33 minutes, but instead, it shows "4 days".
When I change the first max to sum, then it shows a correct maximum of ~33 minutes.
I find that unintuitive, since max of a max should be the same value. And sum doesn't make much sense, but gives the right result.
Why is that? What's going on?
Edit:
Turns out that the graph is being "flattened", i.e. not showing the right values for the maximums. There indeed was a maximum of 3.52 days within that 1 month span.
Still, I don't understand why a sum gives lower values than the max.
